# Menu in sidebar with pages that won't show in the default menu

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, sidebar

I'm using the default Wordpress theme Twenty Eleven.

I was wondering if it's possible to add a menu in the sidebar, that leads to "hidden pages", pages that are not listed in the classic menu bar on top.

I want these menu voices to be on every page, in the default sidebar.

Any useful plugin that does this, or any other method? I wasn't lucky to find one until now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one custom menu for hidden pages

use this plugin [Exclude pages from menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/)

and checked all hidden page, so, this will show only the pages which are checked..

Answer (score 0):

this question belong on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

There is a default widget -called `custom menu`- in which you can select a menu to display.
Do remember to make a sperate menu